# libgdx What texture size?

Tags: libgdx, size, textures

What size for my textures should I use so it looks good on android AND desktop and the performance is good on android? Do I need to create a texture for android **and** a texture for desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way (regarding performance + quality) would be to use mipmaps.
That means you start with a big `Texture`(for example 1024*1024px) and downsample it to a fourth of its size, until you reach a 1x1 image.
So you have a 1024*1024, a 512*512, a 256*256... and a 1*1 `Texture`.

As much as i know you only need to provide the bigest (1024*1024 in the example above) `Texture` and `Libgdx` will create the mipmap chain at runtime.
OpenGL under the hood then decides which `Texture` to use, based on the Pixel to Texel ratio.
Taking a look at the [Texture API](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html), it seems like there is a 2 param constructor, where the first param is the `FileHandle` for the `Texture` and the second param is a `boolean`, indicating, whether you want to use mipmaps or not.
As much as i remember you also have to set the right `TextureFilter`.
To know what `TextureFilter` to you, i suggest to read [this article](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403).

Answer (score 9):

For a typical 2D game you usually want to use the maximum texture size that all of your target devices support. That way you can pack the most images (`TextureRegion`) within a single texture and avoid multiple draw calls as much as possible. For that you can check the maximum texture size of all devices you want to support and take the lowest value. Usually the devices with the lowest size also have a lower performance, therefor using a different texture size for other devices is not necessary to increase the overall performance.

Do not use a bigger texture than you need though. E.g. if all of your images fit in a single 1024x1024 texture then there is no gain in using e.g. a 2048x02048 texture even if all your devices support it.

The spec guarantees a minimum of 64x64, but practically all devices support at least 1024x1024 and most newer devices support at least 2048x2048. If you want to check the maximum texture size on a specific device then you can run:

```
private static int getMaxTextureSize () {
    IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.newIntBuffer(16);
    Gdx.gl.glGetIntegerv(GL20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, buffer);
    return buffer.get(0);
}
```

The maximum is always square. E.g. this method might give you a value of `4096` which means that the maximum supported texture size is 4096 texels in width and 4096 texels in height.

Your texture size should always be power of two, otherwise some functionality like the wrap functions and mipmaps might not work. It does not have to be square though. So if you only have 2 images of 500x500 then it is fine to use a texture of 1024x512.

Note that the texture size is not directly related to the size of your individual images (`TextureRegion`) that you pack inside it. You typically want to keep the size of the regions within the texture as "pixel perfect" as possible. Which means that ideally it should be exactly as big as it is projected onto the screen. For example, if the image (or `Sprite`) is projected 100 by 200 pixels on the screen then your image (the `TextureRegion`) ideally would be 100 by 200 texels in size. You should avoid unneeded scaling as much as possible.

The projected size varies per device (screen resolution) and is not related to your world units (e.g. the size of your `Image` or `Sprite` or `Camera`). You will have to check (or calculate) the exact projected size for a specific device to be sure.

If the screen resolution of your target devices varies a lot then you will have to use a strategy to handle that. Although that's not really what you asked, it is probably good to keep in mind. There are a few options, depending on your needs.

One option is to use one size somewhere within the middle. A common mistake is to use way too large images and downscale them a lot, which looks terrible on low res devices, eats way too much memory and causes a lot of render calls. Instead you can pick a resolution where both the up scaling and down scaling is still acceptable. This depends on the type of images, e.g. straight horizontal and vertical lines scale very well. Fonts or other high detailed images don't scale well. Just give it a try. Commonly you never want to have a scale factor more than 2. So either up scaling by more than 2 or down scaling by more than 2 will quickly look bad. The closer to 1, the better.

As @Springrbua correctly pointed out you could use mipmaps to have a better down scaling than 2 (mipmaps dont help for upscaling). There are two problems with that though. The first one is that it causes bleeding from one region to another, to prevent that you could increase the padding between the regions in the atlas. The other is that it causes more render calls. The latter is because devices with a lower resolution usually also have a lower maximum texture size and even though you will never use that maximum it still has to be loaded on that device. That will only be an issue if you have more images than can fit it in the lowest maximum size though.

Another option is to divide your target devices into categories. For example "HD", "SD" and such. Each group has a different average resolution and usually a different maximum texture size as well. This gives you the best of the both world, it allows you to use the maximum texture size while not having to scale too much. Libgdx comes with the `ResolutionFileResolver` which can help you with deciding which texture to use on which device. Alternatively you can use a e.g. different APK based on the device specifications.